# Testing and validation of the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

friends. I have a question for you regarding object detection. I trained my model and it works perfectly. Now, I have to make a presentation of my work. The problem is that I saw some things about testing and validation. The problem is that after training, I used the model, but I do not remember to use the test set or to run the testing or the validation or hyperparameters tunning. Can you explain to me how these work? I attached below the command I used for training.

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
```

Comment: The command itself is not really helpful. Could you include the code of `train.py` or a link to the github repo or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the main idea of train, test and validation data:

In the beginning you have only one original data set, this set is divided into three distinct subsets: *train set*, *validation set* and *test set*.

You train your model on the train set multiple times, each time with a different set of hyperparameters and evaluate its performance on the validation set to select the best set of hyperparameters. If you found your optimal model, you evaluate its true performance **only once** on the test set, no further optimization. This is what you report as final model performance.

What you truly care about is the *generalization performance* of your model, the holy grail of Machine Learning. This is the ability to handle new and never seen data. To assess this, you need to have spare data your model never has seen before. This is the main purpose of the test set.

Here are some additional links which explain the concept of train,test and validation in more detail: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_sets), [sklearn-guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation), [What is the Difference Between Test and Validation Datasets?](https://machinelearningmastery.com/difference-test-validation-datasets/).

Comment: Thank you very much! I trained a model and it works really good, but I did not use validation. How should I use them? Train and after validate and test on images? Cause my model is implemented for live webcam. So how do I validate? And how do I use hyperparameter tunning?